# Where does docker-machine save the configuration on a remote Ubuntu host running systemd?

Tags: docker, systemd, docker-machine

One can create a remote machine using the command:

```
docker-machine create --driver generic --generic-ip-address=<IP> myremotemachine
```

This command installs and configures docker on the remote host running Ubuntu. And after this the Docker daemon runs using the command:

```
/usr/bin/docker daemon -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock --storage-driver aufs --tlsverify --tlscacert /etc/docker/ca.pem --tlscert /etc/docker/server.pem --tlskey /etc/docker/server-key.pem --label provider=generic
```

I want to adjust some arguments in this command but I cannot find where `docker-machine` wrote this configuration. It must be persistent since, upon restart, the remote Ubuntu host, starts the Docker daemon back using these arguments. They are also not the default arguments since, before running `docker-machine create`, on this Ubuntu server, the daemon was running with fewer arguments (`-H fd://`).

Is there another way to configure `systemd`?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this one.

The following command gave me the answer:

```
$ sudo systemctl status docker
● docker.service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2016-03-26 03:44:11 UTC; 37min ago
...
```

so `docker-machine` writes the `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service` file and there fore this overwrites the values in the default installation file: `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`